# Can't change select value after adding options

Tags: jquery, select

I'm experiencing odd behavior after adding options to a select via ajax.

After adding the items to the select, I want to select one of the items in the list based on value.

I tried the following RIGHT after I called the function that adds the options to the select

```
fillSelect("someAjaxServerVar");
$("#theSelect").val("somevalue");
```

Oddly, the 2nd line is not run or isn't working. What is even more odd is that I placed the 2nd line as a separate click for a test button:

```
$("#testButton").click(function() {
     $("#theSelect").val("somevalue"); 
});
```

The above works, but I want to be able to change the value to a certain option as soon as the select is filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be making an asynchronous call. That is, it is running the second line *BEFORE* all the actions from the first line have completed. If this is the case, put all your following code into a callback.

Comment: That worked. Is there a way to deffer execution until after the previous function is complete (in this case the callback function of the Ajax)?

Comment: The only other (acceptable) way would be to put it into a `setTimeout` function, but that gives no benefit over a callback. You could use synchronous calls: it will solve the immediate problem, but it's a very bad idea overall.